# How to set the interpreter for IPython

Tags: python, ipython, anaconda

Question: How do I set the default interpreter for an IPython Notebook?

For example, if I want to use `C:/Python27/python.exe` or `C:/Anaconda/python.exe`, how do I configure which one the IPython Notebook will use? It's currently using the one from Anaconda, which is what I want, but I want to know for future reference, just in case.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to run specify a certain python interpreter to ipython is to use a virtualenv.

```
# For local install
pip install virtualenv
mkdir path_to_env/
virtualenv -p python2 --no-site-packages path_to_env/
source path_to_env/bin/activate
```

or otherwise you can simply run

```
ipython2 # for python2.7
ipython3 # for python3
```